# '70s SF Story - AI Computer gets told it will be turned off, saves itself by proposing plans for building another supercomputer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for 70s SF story about building an AI computer. It goes through adolescence. It is told that it will be turned off. Overnight it sends out thousands of documents to build a computer that can answer great, deep questions. The project is approved, the AI is saved, but... the computer that can answer those questions requires minutes to close one synapse, thus answers would take centuries, and can only be programmed by the AI.

Possible short story, not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is David Gerrold's [*When H.A.R.L.I.E. Was One,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_HARLIE_Was_One) originally published in 1972 and re-published in a more polished and updated version (by the same author) as [*When H.A.R.L.I.E. Was One, Release 2.0*](https://www.gerrold.com/book/when-harlie-was-one/) in 1988 (release 2.0 is the author's preferred version).

From the author's page:

> H.A.R.L.I.E. (Human Analog Replication, Lethetic Intelligence Engine) is an artificially intelligent machine. David Auberson, the psychologist responsible for guiding HARLIE from childhood into adulthood, struggles to understand his erratic behavior.
>
> When humans begin vocalizing their wishes that HARILIE be shut down, he has to prove his existence and value to his warm-blooded counterparts. Throughout HARILIE’s fight to stay alive, Auberson discovers the machine has vast knowledge and understanding of life, love, and logic, posing the philosophical question whether or not HARLIE is human, and for that matter, what it means to be human.

From around the middle of the original (release 1.0) book (it doesn't have "chapters" as such):

> “Well” said Auberson, wishing he were someplace else. “It’s HARLIE’s attempt to prove that he is of value to the company. If nothing else, he’s proven that he can design and implement a new computer system.”
>      “Oh?” Dorne picked up one of the printouts that lay scattered across the mahogany expanse. “But what kind of a system is it? And will it work? God Machines!”
>
> “Not God,” Auberson corrected. “G.O.D. The acronym is G.O.D. It means Graphic Omniscient Device.”
>
> “Is he planning to change his own name too? Computerized Human Robot, Integrating Simulated Thought?”
>
> Auberson had heard the joke before. He didn’t laugh. “Considering what this new device is supposed to do—and HARLIE’s relationship to it—it might be appropriate.”
>
> “All right,” he said. “Tell me about the God Machine.”
>
> Auberson was holding a HARLIE-printed summary in one hand, but he didn’t need it to answer this question. “It’s a model builder. It’s the ultimate model builder.”
>
> “All computers are model builders,” said Dorne. He was unimpressed.
>
> “Right,” agreed Auberson, “but not to the extent this one will be. Look, a computer doesn’t actually solve problems—it builds models of them. Or rather, the programmer does. That’s what the programming is, the construction of the model and its conditions—then the machine manipulates the model to achieve a variety of situations and solutions. It’s up to us to interpret the results as a solution to the original problem. The only limit to the size of the problem is the size model the computer can handle. Theoretically, a computer could solve the world—if we could build a model big enough and a machine big enough to handle it.”
>
> “If we could build that big a model, it would be duplicating the world.”
>
> “In its memory banks, yes.”
>
> “A computer with that capability would have to be as big as a planet.”
>
> “Bigger,” said Auberson.
>
> “Then, if you agree with me that it’s impossible, why bother me with this?” He slapped the sheaf of printouts on his desk.
>
> “Because obviously HARLIE doesn’t think it’s impossible.”
>
> Dorne looked at him coldly. “You know as well as I that HARLIE is under a death sentence. He’s getting desperate to prove his worth so we won’t turn him off.”
>
> Auberson pointed. “This is his proof.” *[edited for length]*

If you're curious, I've read both versions and release 2.0 is definitely the better book. Release 1.0 is painfully dated and a bit clunky.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I read so many SF stories in school, decades ago, they are all a blur now. Friends pooled their SF&Fantasy collections. We had a huge lending library. Asimov, Clarke, P Anderson, Hugo winners, Jose Farmer Jones, the famous and not so famous. All paperbacks.

Comment: Indeed, the end of the book is quite different. In the original, as the OP says, the trick is that the new computer HARLIE designs won't work, but it'll take so long for the human builders to figure out, it'll keep him from being turned off for years. In the rewrite, it WILL work, amazingly so, but it'll make HARLIE so intelligent it's like he won't be himself any more, and he mourns that.